# Slide menu smoothly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have made some jquery so when someone clicks onto the 2menu" button the off canvas nav-bar shows. However I can't seem to work out, how to get a smooth slide effect when someone opens/closes the menu. Thanks for your help.

My Jquery is:

```
$(".menutrigger").click(function() {
    $(".nav").toggleClass("show-nav");
    $(".page-wrap").toggleClass("page-wrap-menu", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
});
```

Website:

http://ubie-global.ubieportal.co.uk/

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this by adding `transition` to the element with class `page-wrap`.

```
.page-wrap {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;

    /* Transition */
    transition: left ease-in-out 0.3s; 
}
```

> CSS transitions provide a way to control animation speed when changing CSS properties. Instead of having property changes take effect immediately, you can cause the changes in a property to take place over a period of time. For example, if you change the color of an element from white to black, usually the change is instantaneous. With CSS transitions enabled, changes occur at time intervals that follow an acceleration curve, all of which can be customized.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

**Edit**

Additions according to your update.

```
.nav {
    list-style: none;
    background: #fff;
    width: 360px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999;
    top: 0;
    display: block;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateX(360px);
}

.page-wrap {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    overflow: visible;
    transition: all 0.9s ease;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: Also might me worth using transform: translateY(0px) transform: translateY(-360pxpx) so it can be thrown at the gpu (as opposed to left)

Comment: @AndrewBone Absolutely right. Much better to let the device designed for this purpose :)

Comment: @AndrewBone that is a great advice as it will prevent any jittering during the animation which tends to happen on some devices.

Comment: I have done this.The only thing is I can't get the NAV to show on the right (it's now invisible) after doing that ubie-global.ubieportal.co.uk

Comment: @BenAnderson it looks like you did a couple of changes. Remove clear class from .page-wrap

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry I am little bit confused, I dont think I have a "clear" class.

Comment: @BenAnderson I have updated my answer with additional styles to fix your issue.

Comment: @BenAnderson no problem. You don't need to add `show-nav` class anymore to the `nav` class element.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by adding few css changes:

```
.nav {
list-style: none;
background: #fff;
width: 360px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 0;
right: -360px; // changed from 0 to -360px
top: 0;
/* display: none; */
}

.show-nav {
/* display: block !important; */
right: 0; // add this line
}
```

than add this

```
.page-wrap, .nav {
transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. The only thing is the ".nav" is not showing for some reason now on http://ubie-global.ubieportal.co.uk/

Comment: Sorry I didnt add the right: 0; on "show-nav" sorry. My fault

Answer (score 0):

Use a transition like the answers above, but don't animate `left` and `right`, that will be really slow and laggy. Use transform instead.

Comment: I have done this.The only thing is I can't get the NAV to show on the right after doing that http://ubie-global.ubieportal.co.uk/

Comment: It's right: 0 that is the problem. Use left: -360px